# Ajax remote form in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my Rails 3 app I have a simple form like:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "activity", :action => "record"}, :method => "post", :remote => true, :class => "myform") do  %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'name', 'Jack' %>
<% end %>
```

my controller: (activity_controller.rb)

```
def record
 #...something
 respond_to |format|
   format.js          #   app/views/activity/record.js.erb
 end
end
```

In record.js.erb:

```
alert("hello");
```

When I'm trying to submit the form with jquery, from firebug console with:

```
$('.myform').submit();
```

the form makes a post request normally, but controller does not render record.js.

Redirects to localhost/activity/record.

I suppose that something wrong goes with my form..

Can you identify the problem?

Comment: Your form_tag looks okay. But just to be sure, have you included the rails.js library and the `csrf_meta_tag` helper in your layout? That is a very common mistake and you did not mention it.

Comment: FIXED! csrf_meta_tag was ok..The rails.js was the problem. Thanks Danne!

Comment: Great! Then I'll just add an answer so you can mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have included the `rails.js` and the `csrf_meta_tag` helper in your layout. It is a very common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Rails > 3 make sure you have "jquery_ujs.js" which replaces "rails.js"

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs